# Testing a JavaScript File via Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to learn how to unit test a JavaScript file with Jasmine. At this time, I have the following

**/dist/MyJavaScriptFile.min.js**

```
function MyClass() {}
module.exports = MyClass;

MyClass.prototype.test = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

I want to test the functions in this class using Jasmine. In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

**/test/unit/MyJavaScriptFile.spec.js**

```
describe('MyClass', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('MyClass');
    });

    describe('Test', function () {
        it('should write a message', function() {
          MyClass.test('hello from the test.');
        });
    });
});
```

When I attempt to run these tests, from Gulp, I get an error. The error is:

```
Failures: 
1) MyClass Test should write a message
1.1) TypeError: object is not a function
```

My belief is that this is happening because `/dist/MyJavaScriptFile.min.js` or `MyClass` is not loaded as a dependency. I thought I was doing that with the `module('MyClass');` line. However, I do not see how the .spec.js file or the Jasmine test runner would know the location of the definition of `MyClass`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using gulp-jasmine, and where this syntax from: module('MyClass'); Maybe some kind of new js module system?

Comment: Yes I am using `gulp-jasmine`.

Comment: Are you using browserify for your js?

Comment: I am not using browserify. I'm running the tests purely from command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the testing with gulp-jasmine I've includes my js code to be tested to my specs using something like this:

```
// Path is relative to specs location
var someLibToTest = require('path/to/my/js/file');
```

As for as you using here commonjs module syntax, you can do it the same way.
But this works only for console tests, not for browser.

Comment: I think its closer. Now, I get an error that says `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I added `var MyLibrary = require('path/to/file');` at the top of my spec.js file. Then, in the test, I added `if (MyLibrary) { console.log('library loaded'); } else { console.log('no library'); } MyLibrary.test('hello from the test.');` When this code is executed, I see `library loaded` and then the error. So the library is getting loaded, however, the function is not. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: When you write smth like this: MyClass.prototype.test = function(){...}, that means you add a method for instance of MyClass, but not to MyClass. So try var my_inst = new MyClass(); and then my_inst.test('...');

Comment: It was sooooo hard to find this clue to how to test a standalone JavaScript file with Jasmine via Node.   I can't believe how hard it was.